# Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return isExcludingDisplayed() }" After Magento 2.3.4 Upgrade Checkout Cart Page

Tags: error, checkout-page, magento-upgrade, magento2.3.4

> Hi @all, actually after upgrading from Magento 2.2.4 to Magento 2.3.4 below error is
>   showing on checkout cart page.

[image]

> After reaching to checkout cart page Ajax loader is just keep on
>   moving and shipping rates are not loading due to below error in browser
>   console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return isExcludingDisplayed() }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return haveToShowCoupon() }"
Message: haveToShowCoupon is not defined
    at if (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2982), <anonymous>:3:55)
    at ko.computed.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:4381)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2173)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2140)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:2101)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1954)
    at init (knockout.js:4380)
    at knockout.js:3358
    at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1470)
    at knockout.js:3357
```

> If anyone having an idea, please guide me. Thanks in Advance!!!.

Answer (score 4):

The problem might be caused due to the incorrect value or no value available for the isExcludingDisplayed() and haveToShowCoupon() functions.

These two functions are available in shipping.js file

**isExcludingDisplayed** : `module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping.js`

**haveToShowCoupon** : `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js`

If you have customized the shipping js file then cross check the items with default(shipping.js) js file in magento 2.3.4 version

Comment: thanks for answer, i will try and update you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to file changes in Magento 2.3.4, if you have customized module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js, please compare the files with the core file and add those changes in your custom "view/summary/shipping.js" file.